`std::rethrow_exception` not catchable with `catch (const std::exception&)` in Android NDK
I have an Android app that calls C++ code from Java.
This is my C++ code:
try {
  throw std::runtime_error("Test exception");
} catch (...) {
  auto eptr = std::current_exception();
  try {
    std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "Caught std::exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  } catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Caught unknown exception" << std::endl;
  }
}


On iOS, this goes into the catch (const std::exception& e) block and logs "Caught std::exception: Test Exception". ✅
On Android, this goes into the catch (...) block and logs "Caught unknown exception" ❌

Why? How can the same code that only uses std lib produce different results? Does the Android STD/STL library not support exception_ptr?

More Info:
The native C++ library is built with build.gradle/CMake using the following configuration:
android {
  namespace "com.margelo.nitro"

  ndkVersion getExtOrDefault("ndkVersion")
  compileSdkVersion getExtOrIntegerDefault("compileSdkVersion")

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion getExtOrIntegerDefault("minSdkVersion")
    targetSdkVersion getExtOrIntegerDefault("targetSdkVersion")

    externalNativeBuild {
      cmake {
        cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -Wall -Wextra -fstack-protector-all"
        arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared",
                  "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang",
                  "-DANDROID_SUPPORT_FLEXIBLE_PAGE_SIZES=ON"
        abiFilters (*reactNativeArchitectures())

        buildTypes {
          debug {
            cppFlags "-O1 -g"
          }
          release {
            cppFlags "-O2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
      path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
  }

  buildFeatures {
    buildConfig true
    prefab true
    prefabPublishing true
  }

  packagingOptions {
    pickFirst "**/libc++_shared.so"
    excludes = [
      "META-INF",
      "META-INF/**"
    ]
  }
  // ...
}

My CMake:
project(NitroModules)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.0)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_library(NitroModules SHARED MyFile.cpp)

# then I link a bunch of libraries that I need, like fbjni, android, ReactAndroid, ...

I am in a React Native environment which uses SoLoader. The library is then loaded and called from Java:
System.loadLibrary("NitroModules");

The full repo can be found at mrousavy/nitro, which does not include the test code above but shows the full build structure.

You must catch const std::exception& to rethrow const std::exception& with C++ runtime implementations where std::current_exception copies thrown exceptions. The ... catcher doesn't allow to deduce the exception type while making a copy of an untyped exception (copy of void*).

@3CxEZiVlQ wait what? does this mean catch(...) always loses the exception message?

Not "always", only when copied. If not copied you can cast the pointer.

You always need to catch more specific exceptions before more general ones. The first catch block that matches will be chosen , not a more specific one listed later.

I understand that, but I thought catch (...) allows you to catch any kind of exception without losing it's type? Shouldn't std::current_exception inside of a catch (...) block still preserve it's actual type? I can't hardcode add catch blocks for every child-class of std::exception.

Again; the code snippet above works in every C++ runtime I tested on (iOS, macOS, linux), but not on Android. I'm trying to figure out why this could happen?

@3CxEZiVlQ so we're assuming that on Android, current_exception is implemented as a copy? Inside a catch (...) block, what copy constructor does it call then? I thought it has compiler support to call the actual type's copy constructor (runtime_error)?
